# Drawing a percentage bar from input boxes on buttonclick

Tags: javascript, html, variables, percentage

I have two inputboxes and what I want is when a button is clicked for it to display the percentage of the whole represented by the first number.  I found a JavaScript code for drawing a progress bar that I like and the code below works when I "hard code" in a number for it to represent.  If anyone who could help me work the variables I would really appreciate it.

```
<FORM NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="GET">
Enter something in the box: <BR>
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="Input" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="Input2" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="Click" onClick="drawPercentBar(800, Number(Input/Input2*100), 'blue', 'red')">
</FORM>
```

This draws the percentage bar with a NaN% error.

Comment: Do you want the following `Number(Input/Input2*100), 'blue', 'red'` to be used by drawPercentBar function? Or do you want to calculate percentage based on the input data to be passed inside the function instead of hardcoded number 800?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use instead of the Number(Input/Input2*100) the following

```
Number(document.getElementsByName('Input')[0].value/document.getElementsByName('Input2')[0].value*100)
```

But make sure that inputs have values other than 0.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it http://jsfiddle.net/dangoodspeed/JbEdZ/1/

```
$(function() {
    $(".percent").click(function() {
        var percent=parseInt($(".input1").val())/parseInt($(".input2").val());
        $("#percentage").css("width",parseInt(percent*parseInt($("#percentageBar").css("width"))));
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`NaN` stands for *Not A Number*.

So you try to divide `Input/Input2` which they are not numbers. They are names of the textboxes.

Can you try

```
... onclick="drawPercentBar(800, 
                            Number(
                                  document.getElementsByName('Input')[0]/
                                  document.getElementsByName('Input2')[0]*
                                  100
                                  ), 
                            'blue', 
                            'red')" ...
```